# Slipstreaming driver into ISO of OS installer

Tags: windows, iso-image

I have PowerISO and I need to slipstream a DVD device driver into the ISO of Windows Server 2k8 R2 x64 Standard Edition (because when I run this installer it asks for a DVD device driver).

How can I slipstream a driver into an ISO?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766141%28WS.10%29.aspx